# How to call fs.readFile if the file has changed

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a json data that contain some information, the contents of data are derived from post method route in express js. If post method get a new data, fs.writeFile delete all data content and write a new data.

I want call fs.readFile to read the new data automatically after fs.writeFile finish write a new data.

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();

const DATA_FILE = path.join(__dirname, 'data.json');

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/data', (req, res) => {
    // delete all content on data.json file
    fs.writeFile(DATA_FILE, '', (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
    });
    const newData = req.body.data;
    // write new data to data.json file
    fs.writeFile(DATA_FILE, JSON.stringify(newData, null, 4), () => {
        res.json(newData);
        console.log('New data added');
    });
});

// read new data from data.json file
fs.readFile(DATA_FILE, (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    const readNewData = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(readNewData);
});

module.exports = app;
```

fs.readFile located outside of post method because i want to run fs.readFile automatically if the express js start, does not have to wait for action from the post method.

How to call fs.readFile automatically after fs.writeFile has finished write a new data?

Comment: You should call a function to set the new data instead of reading the file.

Comment: You don't use the contents of the file you are reading anywhere

Comment: Why don't you call again the fs.readFile inside the callback of the writeFile? Just wrap this into a function to avoid duplicated code.

Comment: @SLaks thank your for your answer, can i call a function outside the post method?

Comment: @ExplosionPills after reading the file, i process the contents and show to the data page but i don't show the code because that's not my problem, i just make the code simple.

Comment: @HRK44 thank you for your answer, I can't call again the fs.readFile inside the callback of the writeFile because i calculate some data after read it and set the interval continously to send the readed data. if i make two call to read the data, i can make double interval and may result in incompatible data.

Comment: @Ras: You can call a function wherever you want.  Learn the basics of Javascript.

Comment: @SLaks can you show me the code to call a function as you mean? so this question can solved, or if not can you show me the link reference to learn function as you mean.